# We are asked to find all solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Solve the system of linear equations:
$$\begin{cases}
x_2+2x_3+3x_4=a_1 \\ 
x_1+2x_2+3x_3+4x_4=a_2 \\ 
2x_1+3x_2+4x_3+5x_4=a_3
\end{cases}
$$
where:

$1)$ $a_1 = a_2=a_3=0$  and $2)$ $a_1=12, a_2=30, a_3=40$

We are looking for all solutions. Write down the coefficient matrix and use Gauss elimination.

After doing some row operations, I got the following matrix:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -1 & -2 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

In case 1) the linear equations look like: 
$$\begin{cases}
x_1-x_3-2x_4=0 \\ 
x_2+2x_3+3x_4=0 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$
let $x_3 = s$ and $x_4=t$,
therefore, $x_2 = -2t -3s$ and $x_1 = t + 2s$
These are all solutions.

In case 2) I have the same matrix after doing some row operations and the following linear equation system: 
$$\begin{cases}
x_1-x_3-2x_4=0 \\ 
x_2+2x_3+3x_4=12 \\ 
\end{cases}
$$
let $x_3 = t$ and $x_4 = s$, therefore, $x_1 = t + 2s$ and $x_2 = 12 - 2t - 3s$ and these appear to be all solutions.

Could you please confirm with me whether I am on the right track?

Comment: You'll get $x_2+2x_3+3x_4=6$ and $0=-8$ in the second case. The system has a solution iff $a_1+a_3=2a_2$.

Answer (score 1):

RREF yields
$$\begin{matrix}
1&0&-1&2&a_2-a_1\\
0&1&2&3&a_1\\
0&0&0&0&a_1-2a_2+a_3
\end{matrix}$$
Now iff $a_1+a_3=2a_2$ the system has a solution, obviously
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_2-2a_1\\a_1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}
+t\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}.$$
So in both cases you've missed the right solution.